# How to solve "TypeError: callback.apply is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am doing a university project and I've read every post regarding my problem, but I am yet to find a solution. Maybe you can help me out.

The code is the following:

```js
viewerObj.update({_id: currentIDViewerVar} , {minutesWatched: 5},{upsert:true}  , function (err,result) {
                                            
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("Viewer " + userNameVar + " gespeichert");
          console.log("minsWatched" +minsWatched);
});
```

I get the following error. I can't see what I am doing wrong.

```html
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: callback.apply is not a function
    at C:\Users\picco\Desktop\TwitchWatcher_v19\TwitchWatcher\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3388:16
    at Query.callback (C:\Users\picco\Desktop\TwitchWatcher_v19\TwitchWatcher\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2185:9)
    at C:\Users\picco\Desktop\TwitchWatcher_v19\TwitchWatcher\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\kareem\index.js:259:21
    at C:\Users\picco\Desktop\TwitchWatcher_v19\TwitchWatcher\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\kareem\index.js:127:16
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `update` method must follow parameters: `update(doc, options, callback)`. You're passing an extra object.

Comment: I don't know anything about mongodb, but I looked at some docs for `update()` and it sure looks like you're using it incorrectly. So did you review the documentation for the method you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using too many arguments.

Change this:

```
viewerObj.update({_id: currentIDViewerVar} , {minutesWatched: 5},{upsert:true}  , function (err,result) {

      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Viewer " + userNameVar + " gespeichert");
      console.log("minsWatched" +minsWatched);
});
```

to this:

```
viewerObj.update({_id: currentIDViewerVar, minutesWatched: 5}, {upsert:true}, function (err,result) {

      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Viewer " + userNameVar + " gespeichert");
      console.log("minsWatched" +minsWatched);
});
```

See the docs:

- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update

Answer (score 2):

If you're updating a mongoose document, you don't pass in a query as the first parameter.

see the [Docs for Document#update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update).

Thus, this update method expects 3 parameters with the 
third being the callback and you pass in an object (`{upsert: true}`) where the update method expects the callback. That's why you get `callback.apply is not a function`. Simply because `{ upsert: true }` is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was facing this issue with aggregate method of mongoose (5.1.2). The same code was working on <4.9 but got broken on upgrading to 5.

I just added capital braces in my query

```
User.aggregate([{
            $match: {
                isDeleted: 0,
                isActive: 1,
                _id: Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)
            }
        }, {

            $project: {
                claps: 1,
                showIcon: { $cond: [{ $gt: [{ $size: "$userBadges" }, 0] }, 1, 0] },
            }
        }])
            .exec(function (err, data) {});
```

`