# How to insert json object inside nested object in a document based on nested object UUID

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a small project and I am stuck from last month and looking for an exact query to update my document at the exact location...I did my best but didn't get my goal....Please help.

**My Current Query**

```
await test.update(
{
   "subtests.uuid": req.query.sub_uuid
},
{
   $set: {
      $push:
            {
               "subtests.$[element].subtests": req.body
            }
         }
},
{
      arrayFilters: [
         {
            "element.uuid": req.query.sub_uuid
         }
      ]
});
```

With this query, I am getting an error saying (Typeerror: Callback.apply is not a function)

**MongoDb Document Image**

[image]

**Error**

[image]

Thank You to everyone who holds my hand in this complex query (for me it very complex because I am trying to solve it from the month)

Comment: Query looks good check [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0iX57O7eN1E), there would be some client side error.

Comment: @turivishal no...with this query say callback.apply is not a fucntion

Comment: @turivishal server side error

Comment: @turivishal I am posting an image to exact error...please check that...Thanks

Comment: You are passing extra arguments in update function check this related errors too: [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39299429/typeerror-callback-apply-is-not-a-function-node-js-mongodb/39299802), [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42933777/how-to-solve-typeerror-callback-apply-is-not-a-function), check the documentation of update function in mongoose of your related version.